# How to revalidate cache by tag in NEXT js 13 App router

Tags: caching, next.js

I want to revalidate cache by tags `export default async function getData()`. When I call a delete function I want `getdata` to revalidate. How can i achieve this in next.js?

```
{

  const res = await fetch('/api/admin')

 
  if (!res.ok) {
    // This will activate the closest `error.js` Error Boundary
    throw new Error('Failed to fetch data')
  }
 
  return res.json()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using revalidate function from app router, or cache options. Here are two ways that you can try:

Using revalidate:

```
{

  const res = await fetch('/api/admin', 
      { next: { revalidate: 10 }}  //here you can change the time, I put 10 seconds
  )

 
  if (!res.ok) {
    // This will activate the closest `error.js` Error Boundary
    throw new Error('Failed to fetch data')
  }
 
  return res.json()
}
```

Using cache options:

```
{

  const res = await fetch('/api/admin', 
      { cache: 'no-store' }  //this way you will receive new data at every reload of your page
  )

 
  if (!res.ok) {
    // This will activate the closest `error.js` Error Boundary
    throw new Error('Failed to fetch data')
  }
 
  return res.json()
}
```